# Find out what encryptor name my database is using

Tags: sql-server

I want to find what encryptor name my database is using to encrypted. This is database encryption thing.

This is the syntax I see up site of Micosoft.

```
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY  
       WITH ALGORITHM = { AES_128 | AES_192 | AES_256 | TRIPLE_DES_3KEY }  
   ENCRYPTION BY SERVER   
    {  
        CERTIFICATE Encryptor_Name |  
        ASYMMETRIC KEY Encryptor_Name  
    }  
[ ; ]
```

Now I don't know if a symmetric key or a certificate is used to encrypt database.
The encryptor_name for one encrypted with certificate is I find in `sys.certificates` of master database. It is `name` of the row display in `sys.certificates`

What about the ASSYMETRIC KEY. Can you give give me examples to encrypt database with it, then the script to display information of the encryptor_name that it use. (my English is not good. Please suffer me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I don't know if a symmetric key or a certificate is used to encrypt database. The encryptor_name for one encrypted with certificate is I find in sys.certificates of master database. It is name of the row display in sys.certificates

If you look in [sys.database_encryption_keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-database-encryption-keys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it'll tell you what database is encrypted using TDE (filter out TempDB [dbid 2]) along with the type of encryptor (cert/asymmetric key), and the thumbprint of that encryptor which can be used to find the encryptor in either the certificates or asymmetric keys catalog.

> What about the ASSYMETRIC KEY.Can you give give me examples to encrypt database with it, then the script to display information of the encryptor_name that it use.

To use an asymmetric key as an encryptor you'll need a hardware security module (HSM) or a software emulation of an HSM such as Azure Key Vault (AKV) which has a [complete walk through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/setup-steps-for-extensible-key-management-using-the-azure-key-vault?view=sql-server-2017). Other than the specific Azure part of AKV, the same steps would be taken for an on-prem HSM.